# Bounded-ness of range

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

We are give a sequence of the form $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ in the complex metric space.

This sequence of course has a limit at $0$, the range is clearly infinite, however, it is said that the sequence is bounded.

Now, a sequence is bounded if its range is bounded, or if it is given to be both bounded from above and bounded from below.

Why is the sequence bounded from above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence in a set $X$  is the same thing as a function from the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers to $X$.

For example, if $a_n$ is a sequence in the set $X$, then we can define a function $A:\mathbb{N}\to X$ by
$$A(n)=a_n.$$
Conversely, given a function $A:\mathbb{N}\to X$, we can define the sequence $a_n$ by the above formula as well. Thus, sequences and functions from $\mathbb{N}$ are equivalent notions.

---

The "range" of a sequence is just the range of the corresponding function. That is, if $a_n$ is a sequence in the set $X$, then the range of the sequence is
$$\{a_n\in X: n\in\mathbb{N}\}=\{A(n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}=A(\mathbb{N}).$$
Clearly, this set is infinite precisely when there are infinitely many distinct elements of $X$ that are elements of the sequence $a_n$. Thus, it is true that the sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ has an infinite range.

However, *this is separate from the notion of a sequence being bounded*.

Given a metric space $M$, we say that a set $S\subseteq M$ is "bounded" when $S$ is contained inside some ball of the metric space. That is, $S$ is bounded when there is some $p\in M$ and real number $r>0$ such that
$$S\subseteq B(p,r)=\{q\in M: d(p,q)\leq r\}.$$

Given a set $Y$ and a metric space $M$, we say that a function $f:Y\to M$ is bounded when the range of the function, namely the set
$$f(Y)=\{m\in M: m=f(y)\text{ for some }y\in Y\},$$
is a bounded set.

Now, we simply apply this notion to the function corresponding to a sequence. A sequence $a_n$ in a metric space $M$ is equivalent to the function $A:\mathbb{N}\to M$ defined by $A(n)=a_n$. Then a sequence is bounded when the range of the sequence is a bounded set.

We can see that this is the case for your example, because we have
$$x_n=\frac{1}{n}\in B(0,1)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: d(z,0)\leq 1\}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|\leq 1\}$$
for all $n$.

Comment: ohh! it is bounded from both 0 and 1 right? respectively above and below

Comment: The notions of "above" and "below" really only make sense for an *ordering*, which is different. Please read my expanded answer.